# ANFIS library for Java?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, fuzzy-logic

Is there a ready-to-use adaptive neuro fuzzy inference system (ANFIS) library available for Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, NEFCLASS: [NEFCLASS web page at University of Magdeburg](http://fuzzy.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/nefclass/nefclass-j/)